# Avoiding mistakes with PHP multiline strings

Tags: php, string

I can create multiline strings in PHP like this:

```
$something = 'This is
a multiline
string';
```

and it shows up the same way inside a file when I use `file_put_contents()` or simply `echo` it. Are there any disadvantages of creating multiline strings this way that I am missing?

For example, I could also add `\n` or `\r\n` but that seems pointless if the string is being saved exactly the way I am storing it in the variable. Also, what would `HEREDOC` do that won't be accomplished by the simple string above?

Thanks.

Comment: HEREDOC prevents you from having to escape quotes and can optionally handle additional indentation to make your code more readable. Use the syntax that suits your needs, there's no "right" or "wrong".

Comment: The `\n` syntax generally only matters when you want to explicitly control the line ending. I personally use HEREDOCs on SO when I’m writing sample code to represent a dataset (from a remote website, a file, etc.), because I think it is easier to read, and my IDE supports formatting in it usually. Otherwise, there’s [a whole chapter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) on strings with examples of what might be good uses.